# Can a UIPickerView be used for selecting different views to load?

Tags: ios, selection, xib, pageload

Can a `UIPickerView` load a specific `.nib`/`.xib` file from code or UI Interface Designer? Or is there something else I need to use? I've been Googling around for a tutorial on how to do this, and everything I've found so far has been using static content examples (such as colors, countries, dates, etc.) which are meant to be selected, but not necessarily transitioned to from one place to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a NSDictionary with user selectable strings as keys and then strings of the name of the  class/nib you want to instantiate.

When the user selects an option, then you can pull out the code name, and then load the appropriate bundle.

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:theString bundle:whatever];
```

If instead you wanted to open a view controller, you could:

```
UIViewController *c = [NSClassFromString(theString) alloc] initWithNibName:theString bundle:whatever];
```